# Convert Numpy 3D array to 3 R,G,B hex-strings

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, hex

I have large lists containing RGB values for pictures.
I use numpy to create patterns and/or pillow to load pictures and convert them to 3D-numpy arrays (int32). Now i want to restructure my array into hex-strings in a weird way:
Three hex-strings for R, G, B in this structure: '0000FFFF', where the first 4 characters always have to be zero, then 2 characters represent pixel n+1 and the last 2 cahracters represent pixel n.
I already have done this with a code which takes too long for larger images and i require some improvement. What i got so far:

```
import numpy
import numpy.matlib
#from matplotlib.colors import rgb2hex
import time

def pairwise(iterable):
    """Create a paired-list from a list."""
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

def test(imgSize=[480,640], brightness=[255,255,255]):
    
    #generate pattern
    startPattern = time.time()
    patternDescription = 'Stripe Test'
    pattern = numpy.zeros((imgSize[0], imgSize[1], 3))
    line = (numpy.r_[:imgSize[1]]%255)/255
    colorChR = numpy.matlib.repmat(line, imgSize[0], 1)
    colorChG = numpy.matlib.repmat(line, imgSize[0], 1)
    colorChB = numpy.matlib.repmat(line, imgSize[0], 1)
    colorChR[:, :] = 0
    colorChR[:, 0:60] = 1
    colorChG[:, :] = 0
    colorChG[:, 0:60] = 1
    colorChB[:, :] = 0
    colorChB[:, 0:60] = 1
    pattern[:, :, 0] = colorChR
    pattern[:, :, 1] = colorChG
    pattern[:, :, 2] = colorChB
    stopPattern = time.time()
    print('TIME: Pattern generation:  ' + str(round(stopPattern-startPattern,3)) + ' s. ')
    # first reshape
    startReshape = time.time()
    pattern[:, :, 0] = pattern[:, :, 0]*brightness[0] # red brightness multiplicator
    pattern[:, :, 1] = pattern[:, :, 1]*brightness[1] # green brightness multiplicator
    pattern[:, :, 2] = pattern[:, :, 2]*brightness[2] # blue brightness multiplicator
    
    img = pattern.astype(int)
    
    # IDEALLY I WANT TO CHANGE THE CODE ONLY FROM HERE ON


    # redValues = pattern[:,:,0].astype(int)
    # greenValues = pattern[:,:,1].astype(int)
    # blueValues = pattern[:,:,2].astype(int)
    
    
#     test = ("0000" + ("{:0>2X}" * len(redValues))).format(*tuple(redValues[::-1]))
    
#     numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':hex})
    
#     #test = [ rgb2hex(img[i,:]) for i in range(img.shape[0]) ]
#     rgb2hex = lambda r,g,b: '%02X%02X%02X' %(r,g,b)
#     test = [ rgb2hex(*img[i,:]) for i in range(img.shape[0]) ]
# #    img = numpy.array2string(img, formatter = {'int':lambda img: hex(img)})
    imgReshape = numpy.reshape(img, (1, imgSize[0]*imgSize[1]*3)) #necessary?
    redValues = imgReshape[0][0::3] #red values (0, 3, 6, ..)
    greenValues = imgReshape[0][1::3] #green values (1, 4, 7, ..)
    blueValues = imgReshape[0][2::3] #blue values (2, 5, 8, ..)
    stopReshape = time.time()
    print('TIME: Reshape into colors: ' + str(round(stopReshape-startReshape,3)) + ' s. ')
    
    
    redString = ''
    greenString = ''
    blueString = ''
    outData = dict()
    startString = time.time()

    for i, j in pairwise(redValues):
        tempRed = "0000%02X%02X" % (int(j), int(i))
        redString += tempRed
        
    for i, j in pairwise(greenValues):
        tempGreen = "0000%02X%02X" % (int(j), int(i))
        greenString += tempGreen
        
    for i, j in pairwise(blueValues):
        tempBlue = "0000%02X%02X" % (int(j), int(i))
        blueString += tempBlue

    outData['red'] = redString
    outData['green'] = greenString
    outData['blue'] = blueString
    stopString = time.time()
    print('TIME: String formatting:   ' + str(round(stopString-startString, 3)) + ' s')
    print('DATATEST: First 200 red chars: ' + str(outData['red'][0:200]))
    print('DATATEST: First 200 green chars: ' + str(outData['green'][0:200]))
    print('DATATEST: First 200 blue chars: ' + str(outData['blue'][0:200]))
    #return outData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use numpy array instead:

```
redValues = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10, 2))

red = np.array(redValues).reshape(-1, 2)
red_channel = (red[:, 1] << 8) + red[:, 0]

redString = ''.join(map(lambda val: f'0000{val:04x}', red_channel))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My array only consists of zeroes after this line:
    red_channel = red[:, 1] << 8 + red[:, 0]. Also any(red_channel>0) yields False. :(

Comment: What are the values in redValues and shape? Type redValues.shape

Comment: The operations are converting your array into array of x_i, x_i+1, shifting x_i+1 8 bits to the left and adding it to x_i

Comment: Type red.shape, red[:10]

Comment: yeah, but does this make sense? If i would have 255, 255 in the first line (col 0, col 1), this would mean that i would shift 255 (bin: 1111 1111) to the left > 4080 (bin: 1111 1111 0000) and it to add x_i resulting in something like bin: 1 0000 0000 1110 1111 ?

Comment: result from red.shape, red[:10] >>
((153600, 2),
 array([[255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [255, 255]]))

Comment: Sorry. It was missing parentheses. It should work now. Take out the first line.

Comment: Ah, i saw you edited your first reply and extended it with brackets. Works now - very much appreaciated !!